# Why does my code say that I'm trying to convert decimal to double and how can I fix it?

Tags: c#

I want to run this program, but it won't let me because I get an error saying I'm trying to convert 'decimal' to 'double'. I don't understand why. Nor do I know how I can fix this issue.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        decimal[] hvValues = inputString.Split().Select(decimal.Parse).ToArray();

        decimal sinTest = hvValues[1];
        decimal sinV = Math.Sin(sinTest);
        decimal hypotenusan = hvValues[0] / sinV;
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(hypotenusan));
    }
}
```

Comment: May I guess at the line causing the error?  Is it, `decimal hypotenusan = hvValues[0] / sinV;` ?

Comment: `Math.Sin` takes a `double` and returns a `double`.  Yet you are using `decimal` throughout your code.

Comment: `Math.Sin` is only defined for `double` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sin?view=netframework-4.7.2) and therefore accepts and returns only a `double`.

Comment: You can't cast double to decimal implicitly because the conversion can't be secured to be lossless. Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817866/why-cant-double-be-implicitly-cast-to-decimal)

Comment: `Math.Sin` returns double, thats why.

Comment: @Vulpex OP is doing the reverse.

Comment: @itsme86 it doesn't matter, it isn't allowed either way as far I know.

Comment: Well for clarity, you should speak to what the OP is trying to do, not something that is seemingly irrelevant.

Comment: Your code does not say that you are trying... Only a single line of code is saying that, not your whole code. There are even little colored wiggly lines in Visual Studio that highlight the line of code that makes problems. From there, it is just a matter of looking up the documentation of what type of arguments the offending method/function accepts and what type of results it returns (if any). Just use your eyes and follow the bread crumbs ;-)

Comment: Read the third paragraph under "Conversion Considerations":  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.7.2#conversion-considerations

Comment: Just turn *everything* to double, then your code will work. But you should try to understand what the difference between `double` and `decimal` is, at some point.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, as you seem to be new to programming, just use double instead of decimal:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        double[] hvValues = inputString.Split().Select(double.Parse).ToArray();

        double sinTest = hvValues[1];
        double sinV = Math.Sin(sinTest);
        double hypotenusan = hvValues[0] / sinV;
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(hypotenusan));
    }
}
```

This will make it work, however at some point you should try to understand what the difference between `double` and `decimal` is. Also it will help that you learn to understand compiler errors and why your IDE puts red underline under certain parts of your code.