# JavaScript to C# Numeric Precision Loss

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, msgpack, binary-serialization

When serializing and deserializing values between JavaScript and C# using SignalR with MessagePack I am seeing a bit of precision loss in C# on the receiving end.

As an example I am sending the value 0.005 from JavaScript to C#. When the deserialized value appears on the C# side I am getting the value `0.004999999888241291`, which is close, but not 0.005 exactly. The value on the JavaScript side is `Number` and on the C# side I am using `double`.

I have read that JavaScript can't represent floating point numbers exactly which can lead to results like `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004`. I suspect the issue I am seeing is related to this feature of JavaScript.

The interesting part is that I am not seeing the same issue going the other way. Sending 0.005 from C# to JavaScript results in the value 0.005 in JavaScript.

**Edit**: The value from C# is just shortened in the JS debugger window. As @Pete mentioned it does expand to something that is not 0.5 exactly (0.005000000000000000104083408558). This means the discrepancy happens on both sides at least.

JSON serialization does not have the same issue since I am assuming it goes via string which leaves the receiving environment in control wrt parsing the value into its native numerical type.

I am wondering if there is a way using binary serialization to have matching values on both sides.

If not, does this mean that there is no way to have 100% accurate binary conversions between JavaScript and C#?

Technology used:

- JavaScript
- .Net Core with SignalR and msgpack5

My code is based on [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/messagepackhubprotocol?view=aspnetcore-3.1).
The only difference is that I am using `ContractlessStandardResolver.Instance`.

Comment: Floating point representation in C# is not exact for every value as well. Have a look at the serialized data. How do you parse it in C#?

Comment: What type do you use in C#? Double is known to have such issue.

Comment: I use the built in message pack serilization/deserialization that comes with signalr and it's message pack integration.

Comment: Floating point values are never precise. If you need precise values, use strings (formatting issue) or integers (e.g. by multiplying by 1000).

Comment: Can you check the deserialized message? The text you got from js, before c# converts in a object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This has been [fixed in next release (5.0.0-preview4)](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20333).

**Original Answer**

I tested `float` and `double`, and interestingly in this particular case, only `double` had the problem, whereas `float` seems to be working (i.e. 0.005 is read on server).

Inspecting on the message bytes suggested that 0.005 is sent as type [`Float32Double`](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#float-format-family) which is a 4-byte / 32-bit IEEE 754 single precision floating point number despite `Number` is 64 bit floating point.

Run the following code in console confirmed the above:

```
msgpack5().encode(Number(0.005))

// Output
Uint8Array(5) [202, 59, 163, 215, 10]
```

*mspack5* does provide an option to force 64 bit floating point:

```
msgpack5({forceFloat64:true}).encode(Number(0.005))

// Output
Uint8Array(9) [203, 63, 116, 122, 225, 71, 174, 20, 123]
```

However, the `forceFloat64` option is not used by *signalr-protocol-msgpack*.

Though that explains why `float` works on the server side, [**but there isn't really a fix for that as of now**](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp/issues/867#issuecomment-606365902). Let's wait what [Microsoft says](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20333).

#### Possible workarounds

- Hack msgpack5 options? Fork and compile your own msgpack5 with `forceFloat64` default to true?? I don't know.
- Switch to `float` on server side
- Use `string` on both sides
- Switch to `decimal` on server side and write custom `IFormatterProvider`. *`decimal` is not primitive type, and [`IFormatterProvider<decimal>` is called for complex type properties](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp/issues/867#issuecomment-606953001)*
- Provide method to retrieve `double` property value and do the `double` -> `float` -> `decimal` -> `double` trick
- Other unrealistic solutions you could think of

#### TL;DR

The problem with JS client sending single floating point number to C# backend causes a known floating point issue:

```
// value = 0.00499999988824129, crazy C# :)
var value = (double)0.005f;
```

For direct uses of `double` in methods, the issue could be solved by a custom `MessagePack.IFormatterResolver`:

```
public class MyDoubleFormatterResolver : IFormatterResolver
{
    public static MyDoubleFormatterResolver Instance = new MyDoubleFormatterResolver();

    private MyDoubleFormatterResolver()
    { }

    public IMessagePackFormatter<T> GetFormatter<T>()
    {
        return MyDoubleFormatter.Instance as IMessagePackFormatter<T>;
    }
}

public sealed class MyDoubleFormatter : IMessagePackFormatter<double>, IMessagePackFormatter
{
    public static readonly MyDoubleFormatter Instance = new MyDoubleFormatter();

    private MyDoubleFormatter()
    {
    }

    public int Serialize(
        ref byte[] bytes,
        int offset,
        double value,
        IFormatterResolver formatterResolver)
    {
        return MessagePackBinary.WriteDouble(ref bytes, offset, value);
    }

    public double Deserialize(
        byte[] bytes,
        int offset,
        IFormatterResolver formatterResolver,
        out int readSize)
    {
        double value;
        if (bytes[offset] == 0xca)
        {
            // 4 bytes single
            // cast to decimal then double will fix precision issue
            value = (double)(decimal)MessagePackBinary.ReadSingle(bytes, offset, out readSize);
            return value;
        }

        value = MessagePackBinary.ReadDouble(bytes, offset, out readSize);
        return value;
    }
}
```

And use the resolver:

```
services.AddSignalR()
    .AddMessagePackProtocol(options =>
    {
        options.FormatterResolvers = new List<MessagePack.IFormatterResolver>()
        {
            MyDoubleFormatterResolver.Instance,
            ContractlessStandardResolver.Instance,
        };
    });
```

The resolver is not perfect, as casting to `decimal` then to `double` slows the process down and [it could be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817866/why-cant-double-be-implicitly-cast-to-decimal).

**However**

As per the OP pointed out in the comments, this **cannot** solve the issue if using complex types having `double` returning properties.

**Further investigation revealed the cause of the problem in MessagePack-CSharp:**

```
// Type: MessagePack.MessagePackBinary
// Assembly: MessagePack, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4a0369545f0a1be
// MVID: B72E7BA0-FA95-4EB9-9083-858959938BCE
// Assembly location: ...\.nuget\packages\messagepack\1.9.11\lib\netstandard2.0\MessagePack.dll

namespace MessagePack.Decoders
{
  internal sealed class Float32Double : IDoubleDecoder
  {
    internal static readonly IDoubleDecoder Instance = (IDoubleDecoder) new Float32Double();

    private Float32Double()
    {
    }

    public double Read(byte[] bytes, int offset, out int readSize)
    {
      readSize = 5;
      // The problem is here
      // Cast a float value to double like this causes precision loss
      return (double) new Float32Bits(bytes, checked (offset + 1)).Value;
    }
  }
}
```

The above decoder is used when needing to convert a single `float` number to `double`:

```
// From MessagePackBinary class
MessagePackBinary.doubleDecoders[202] = Float32Double.Instance;
```

#### v2

This issue exists in v2 versions of MessagePack-CSharp. I have filed [an issue on github](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp/issues/867), [though the issue is not going to be fixed](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp/issues/867#issuecomment-606365902).

Comment: Interesting findings. One challenge here is that the issue applies to any number of double properties on a complex object, so it will be tricky to target double directly I think.

Comment: @TGH Yeah, you're right. I believe it is a bug in MessagePack-CSharp. See my updated for details. For now, you might need to use `float` as a workaround. I don't know if they have fixed that in v2. I will take a look once I have some time. However, the problem is v2 is not compatible with SignalR yet. Only preview versions (5.0.0.0-*) of SignalR can use v2.

Comment: This is not working in v2 either. I have raised a bug with MessagePack-CSharp.

Comment: @TGH Unfortunately there isn't any fix on the server side as per the discussion in github issue. The best fix would be to get the client side to send 64bits rather than 32bits. I noticed there is an option to force that to happen, but Microsoft doesn't expose that (from my understanding). Just updated answer with some nasty workarounds if you want to take a look. And good luck on this issue.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting lead. I will take a look at that. Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: I think you have identified the only practical solution to this problem. I did a quick POC in the signalR repo. I am thinking something like the following might work: https://github.com/thelgevold/aspnetcore/commit/b8a105ed0763e87334c5f41a5dcc0f620fc112c1

Comment: That looks promising.

Answer (score 13):

Please check the precise value you are sending to a bigger precision. Languages typically limits the precision on print to make it look better.

```
var n = Number(0.005);
console.log(n);
0.005
console.log(n.toPrecision(100));
0.00500000000000000010408340855860842566471546888351440429687500000000...
```