# Compound Interest Calculation

Tags: c#

I have this C# code which calculate compound interest plus principal amount every year.

```
static void CompoundInterest(double principal, double interestRate, double years, double annualCompound)
    {
        var total = 0.0;
        for (int t = 1; t < years + 1; t++)
        {
            total = principal * Math.Pow((1 + interestRate / annualCompound),
                                     (annualCompound * t));
            Console.Write("Your Total for Year {0} "
                        + "is {1}. \n", t, total);
        }
    }
```

When I tested it with

```
 CompoundInterest(1000, 0.05, 3, 12);
```

and the output is

```
Your Total for Year 1 is 1051.161897881733.
Your Total for Year 2 is 1104.941335558327.
Your Total for Year 3 is 1161.4722313334678.
```

How should I round it accurately? Another question is `Math.Pow` uses `double` but in financial calculation, we need `decimal`. How do I fix this? Convert into decimal after `Math.Pow`?

Comment: regarding double to decimal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007159/cast-a-double-variable-to-decimal and rounding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks. So, should I convert double to decimal and then only round it? Will the accuracy be affected by doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some test by rounding first and converting to decimal and by converting to decimal and then rounding afterword. Both gave the same results.

But from the logic point of view, I would convert first than rounding after words. This way I will have better control of testing what is converted and what is rounded.

For converting there are different answers, but I found this method [Convert.ToDecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netcore-3.1) is supported by all .net frameworks and cores.

ex. `decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(double_value);`

And then you [decimal.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_System_Int32_), which some one has asked and got answer here [Why does .NET use banker's rounding as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default)

Just in case reference to [Floating-point numeric types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a double to a decimal directly if you'd like

```
decimal decimalTotal = (decimal)total;
```

As for rounding, there is a built-in function, Math.Round, that takes a variety of number formats. It has a overload to specify how many decimal points you want.

```
decimal roundedDecimal = Math.Round(decimalTotal, 2);
```

Comment: You should also read up on how various rounding schemes work. For example *Bankers Rounding* would take `1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4` and round it to `1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4`