# C# if statement and decimal variable is less than 1 and greater than 0

Tags: c#, if-statement, decimal

I'm new to programing and figured out that if you are dealing with money, decimal is better to use. I noticed that if I use a if statement like,

`if (salePrice < 0.01)`

If salePrice is a decimal, it will not work because .01 represents a double-precision floating-point number. If I change everything to double it does work. But, I need to keep everything as a decimal and you really can't mix decimal with double as far as I know. Setting it to `if (salePrice == 0)` will still show $0.00 by taking the itemCost - (itemCost * 99.99...%) is not what I want. Is there any way around this or am I stuck with `if (salePrice < 1)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast a Double Variable to Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007159/cast-a-double-variable-to-decimal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 'm' postfix to specify it's a decimal, not a float or double:

```
//This works
if (salePrice < 0.01m)
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0) for more details.

Comment: If you are curious about "Why `m`?", it stands for _money_